# What is some of the equipment and uniform of the German Empire officer and some places I could get it?

Tags: world-war-one, uniform, imperial-germany

I want to go for an infantry officer from Prussia and this is the best image I can find. I don't know how this is basic but it cant be solved with Wikipedia other wise I would have found my answer because I have look on that website for a long time

[image: Prussian Officer model]

Comment: [Köpenick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Voigt) is the place to go.

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: Does this help? [Imperial German Uniforms 1842 to 1918](https://www.kaisersbunker.com/gtp/)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of people who re-enact WWI on a small scale, and there are companies who supply reproduction uniforms and equipment. A web search for "re-enactment WWI German uniform" will find suppliers.

There is also a thriving hobby of *collecting* WWI uniforms and equipment, as "militaria". eBay lists lots of it, and there are specialist dealers.

These two hobbies overlap, and also interact with professional suppliers of uniforms for film, TV and stage productions. If you're willing to spend some money, there's as much stuff out there as you want.

Comment: i have tried this i would not be here if I head found my answer there

Comment: i cant find it i have look for it for a long time and I would not have asked it here if I cant find it other places

Comment: @hunterpainter - Please edit the question to add that information.